# how to format an sql table when all items have the same length?

Tags: python, sql

so I want the program to have the headers of the table to be this (this is just going to be a text based table format nothing special):

```
print(": Name of item  :  quantity  :  cost(£)  :  date  :")
```

and I was originally planning for the items selected to go under each column with the colons aligning perfectly using this query and function:

```
c.execute("SELECT item FROM outflows1 ")
for row in data:
    print(":",row, " "*(14-len(row)),":")
```

however after this did not give the desired output I checked the length of row and it was only 1 no matter the length of the item in the row. So what I am wondering is how I can get around this problem of the lengh so I can format this table as intended. any help would be great thanks :))

Comment: Is `row` a string?

Comment: @SamM no row is the item from the sql table. I guess it includes a string but I believe its a tuple

Comment: Use a string formatting operator with a field with specification.